# Is it possible to pass JSON object to the RabbitMQ queue using java application?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want to pass JSON object to the RabbitMQ queue.

In the below code, I am using `obj.toJSONString().getBytes()` for converting Json object in to string, Is it possible to pass JSON object in the queue instead passing as string.

```html
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Transaction","Test value");        
channel.basicPublish("", queueName, null, obj.toJSONString().getBytes()); 
System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + obj.toJSONString() + "'");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can only send the data as bytes to a rabbitmq queue. So we have to convert the json object into string. In your code snippet, you have done by using the code - `obj.toJSONString().getBytes()`. This is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

No Its not possible
In Rabbit MQ you can pass objects if object type is implementing Serializable interface.

There is another way you can write is using apache-commons jar's to serialize your object:

```
SerializationUtils.serialize(obj);
```

This Guy will Serializes an Object to a byte array for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Rabbit MQ you can pass objects which implements Serializable interface.

public class obj implements Serializable {
... your object code here
}